# Retrieving Locations(LatLng) Inside GoogleMap Viewport from Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, viewport

If I were to implement in getting a list of latlng inside a given viewport from a `mySQL` database, I will query something like `SELECT * FROM places WHERE lat>=$east && lat<=$west && lng>=south && lng<=north`

I wonder if how can we efficiently do something like that in Firebase?

example structure,

```
-lats
 ---12.34567
 ---23.45678


-lngs
 ---12.34567
 ---23.45678
```

I am thinking of retrieving each node then compare each of their children on the client side.

```
for(double lat: lats){
    if(lat >= east && lat <= west){
       myLats.add(lat);
    }
}

for(double lng: lngs){
    if(lng >= south && lng <= north){
       myLngs.add(lngs);
    }
}
```

I thought that this is inefficient if we have 1000 children from lat and 1000 children from lng.

I wonder if there are better approach than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database queries can only query on a single condition. So ordinarily it would not be possible to query for a location, since that requires filtering on both latitude and longitude.

Luckily there is a library called [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire), which (through the magic of [geo-hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)) allows running geo-queries against the Firebase Database. A sample [geo-query from the documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#geo-queries):

```
// creates a new query around [37.7832, -122.4056] with a radius of 0.6 kilometers
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(37.7832, -122.4056), 0.6);
```

I recommend you check out [GeoFire for Java](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#geo-queries).

Comment: Not the exact equivalent but perhaps I was still able to come up with the behaviour that I need.